# Ruby 3.0 на OSX 10.9.5 это реально?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Задача: установить в идеале ruby 3.0 или максимально доступную для моей системы (OSX 10.9.5)

- обновлять ОС большого желания нет. Сейчас, впрочем как и все предыдущие годы комп отлично работает, стабильно и никаких тормозов, не уверен, что новые версии ОС будут столь же проворны..)
  Для управления версиями Ruby предполагал использовать RVM, но и она не ставится.
  В прочем как не ставится и Homebrew

XCODE из систему сейчас удален (был 6.2), если можно без него, уж больно много места требует. Было бы здорово обойтись command line interface для Xcode.

Просто установить из терминала у меня не получилось, что у меня старая версия(((. Более того я не уверен,что правильно понимаю минимально необходимую инфраструктуру для установки ruby 3.0 на мак: Homebrew + RVM + Ruby).
Сейчас у меня ruby 2.0.0p481 (шла в системе)

Comment: Не так давно я работала на 10.10 (Yosemite), 2.6 точно туда ставилась, 2.7 тогда ещё не было. Xcode тоже стоял, так же как и Homebrew. Как быть без Homebrew - не очень представляю, честно говоря.

Comment: Василиса, Homebrew нужен это факт, просто на 10.9.5, стандартной командой из терминала он уже не ставиться(( наверняка это можно сделать, но вероятно это тоже вопрос версии homebrew. Было бы здорово обойтись без Xcode (может достаточно будет его инструментов командной строки? Ну если нет, то не конечно и Xcode поставлю, вопрос, только в том, что на 10.9.5 у меня Xcode выше 6.2 не встает, вроде как можно 6.3 поставить, вопрос лишь в том, будет ли этого достаточно для установки Ruby 3.0...?  Другими словами надо поставить Ruby 3.0 на OSX 10.9.5, остальное уже сопутствующие сложности)

Comment: при попытке установить Homebrew на OS X 10.9.5

Comment: при попытке установить Homebrew на OS X 10.9.5 ( командой: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"  ),  получаю ошибку: Your OS X version is too old    Подскажите, как поставить последнюю менеджера пакетов доступную для 10.9.5

Comment: Видимо, придется сдаваться и обновляться до актуальной версии MacOS... Ни с инструментами командной строки ни с полным XCode, не получается поставить Homebrew, пишет что моя ОС , безнадежно устарела :  Your OS X version is too old